# How can i increment "id" to infinity and print same value ranges

Tags: php

I have a port `$id` and `$port` value to enter in an HTML form. Then, the two inputs will generate a `$key`.

Here, when I enter `$id =0` and `$port = (something between 1014 to 65535)`, it should generate IP `range($key)` from 1 to 64. it does generate them.

```
<div id="port" align="center">
    <form  action="NetRules.php" method="GET">
        <input type="number" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>" placeholder="enter real IP">
        <br/>
        <input type="number" name="port" value="<?php echo $port ?>" placeholder="enter port ID">
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Suche">       
    </form>
</div>
<?php

$portRanges = [1024, 2031, 3039, 4047,5055,6063,7071,8079,9087,10095,
               11103,12111,13119,14127,15135,16143,17151,18159,19167,
               20175,21183,22191,23199,24207,25215,26223,27231,28239,
               29247,30255,31263,32272,33279,34287,35295,36303,37311,
               38319,39327,40335,41343,42351,43359,44367,45375,46383,
               47391,48399,49407,50415,51423,52431,53439,54447,55455,
               56463,57471,58479,59497,60945,61503,62511,63519,64527,
               65535];

if(isset($_GET['submit']) && isset($_GET['port'])) {
    $port = $_GET['port'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    if($id == 0){
    foreach($portRanges as $key => $value) {
        if(array_key_exists($key+1, $portRanges) && $port >= $value && $port < $portRanges[$key+1]+1) {

            break;
        }
    }
    $id++;
    }
}
?>
<!--Here We Fetch The IP Range-->
<div align="center">
    <form id="content1">
        <h3>Private IP Address:</h3>
        <input type="number" name="IP range" value="<?php echo $key ?>"> 
    </form>
</div>
```

The problem is when I enter or dont enter `$id`, it still generates same `$key`, this PHP code does not include `$Id`. I want the `$Id` to get incremented after 64.

I.e. `$id=0` for `$portRanges[1024-65535]` should generate `$key` from 0-64

Similarly: `$id=1` for `$portRanges[1024-65535]` should generate `$key` from 0-64.

The `$id` should increase infinity here. 
I tried the above method and it does not work. 
Any assistance would be really appreciated. 
Thanks!!

Comment: You don't get any value when not entering an id because blank is not equal to 0. For your code to run id has to be zero.

Comment: Yes, but i enter my $id=0 in html form. Isn't that enough?

Comment: or can you highlight me if there is another way? Would be a great help to end my project.

Comment: You said when you don't enter an id. When i enter in 0 and a valid port number it works. I don't really understand what your trying to do. As the code id you could probably take out the foreach. Does the id even matter.

Comment: Yes, when I enter $id = 1 and $port= 1024(or some range), it should match the #portRange again. So, the $Id will start form 0 - infinity.

Comment: I need the $Id to generate same $key from 0-255(sorry, not infinity)

Comment: for example, $Id (anything between 0-255) and $port(anything between 1024- 35535) should print specific $key. When I enter $Id = 0 and $port from 1024-65535 and will print $key. similary $id=1, $id=2 . . . $id=255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do.

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$portRanges = [1024,2031,3039,4047,5055,6063,7071,8079,9087,10095,
               11103,12111,13119,14127,15135,16143,17151,18159,19167,
               20175,21183,22191,23199,24207,25215,26223,27231,28239,
               29247,30255,31263,32272,33279,34287,35295,36303,37311,
               38319,39327,40335,41343,42351,43359,44367,45375,46383,
               47391,48399,49407,50415,51423,52431,53439,54447,55455,
               56463,57471,58479,59497,60945,61503,62511,63519,64527,
               65535];

$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
$port = isset($_GET['port']) ? $_GET['port'] : 1024;
if($id < 0 or $id > 255){
    echo 'ID out of range. 0-255<br>';
    $id = 0;
}
if(array_search($port, $portRanges) === False){
    echo 'Invalid Port.<br>';
    $port = 1024;
}

$select = '<SELECT name="port" >';
foreach($portRanges as $key => $value) {
    if($port == $value){
        $opt = ' SELECTED ';
    } else {
        $opt = '';
    }
    $select .= "<option $opt >$value</option>";
}
$select .= '</SELECT>';
$form ='
<div id="port" align="center">
    <form  method="GET">
        <input type="number" name="id" value="'.$id.'" placeholder="enter real IP">
        <br/>
        '.$select.'
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Suche">       
    </form>
</div>

<div align="center">
    <form id="content1">
        <h3>Private IP Address:</h3>
        <input type="number" name="IP range" value="'.array_search($port, $portRanges).'"> 
    </form>
</div>
';

echo $form;
```